# case when grouping in sql

Tags: sql

i have following query working..

```
select count(id) ,
case
when age < 0 then 'less than 0'
when age >= 0 and age <=30 then '0-30'
when age >= 31 and age <=60 then '31-60'
when age >= 61 and age <=90 then '61-90'
when age >= 91 then '91+'
when age = null then 'NO INFORMATION'
else 'no catagory'
end
from queue where DATE between '01-Apr-2011' and '05-May-2011'
group by case
when age < 0 then 'less than 0'
when age >= 0 and age <=30 then '0-30'
when age >= 31 and age <=60 then '31-60'
when age >= 61 and age <=90 then '61-90'
when age >= 91 then '91+'
when age = null then 'NO INFORMATION'
else 'no catagory'
end
/
```

now my requirement is that, i dont want to use CASE clause again for grouping it with count..
by using CASE clause only once i want the same result..

also i want a sequence always to be followed by result of this query..
for ex it always print count first for 'less than 0' then for '0-30' and so on.. even if there is 0 count found for interval say 31-60 it should print 0 for that it interval...

can anyone plzz help..
thanx in advance

Comment: also i want a sequence always to be followed by result of this query.. for ex it shud always print count first for 'less than 0' then for '0-30' and so on.. even if there is 0 count found for interval say 31-60 it should print 0 for that it interval..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *have* to group by on all non-aggregated, non-constant  columns and expressions
So you either repeat the entire CASE or you use a derived table like this if you don't 
want to repeat it.

This is standard SQL, should work in all mainstream RDBMS

```
SELECT
  COUNT(id), AgeRange
FROM
  (
  select
    id,
    case
    when age < 0 then 'less than 0'
    when age >= 0 and age <=30 then '0-30'
    when age >= 31 and age <=60 then '31-60'
    when age >= 61 and age <=90 then '61-90'
    when age >= 91 then '91+'
    when age = null then 'NO INFORMATION'
    else 'no catagory'
    end AS AgeRange
  from queue 
  where DATE between '01-Apr-2011' and '05-May-2011'
  ) T
GROUP BY
  AgeRange;
```

Edit: Note I aliased the CASE as AgeRange and grouped on that.

`GROUP BY (ordinal)` isn't standard SQL. It doesn't work in SQL Server

Comment: @OlegDok: no, GROUP BY 2 **isn't** standard SQL.

Comment: @gbn - Missed answer, it was not intended to you. Meanwhile - +1 for simpler answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(id),
       CASE
           WHEN age < 0 THEN 'less than 0'
           WHEN age >= 0 AND age <=30 THEN '0-30'
           WHEN age >= 31 AND age <=60 THEN '31-60'
           WHEN age >= 61 AND age <=90 THEN '61-90'
           WHEN age >= 91 THEN '91+'
           WHEN age = null THEN 'NO INFORMATION'
           ELSE 'no catagory'
       END
FROM queue
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '01-Apr-2011' AND '05-May-2011'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: I believe GROUP BY 1 implies - "group by first non-aggregate column". count(id) will not be considered as column number one since it is an aggregate column (if that is the right term).

Comment: @WebUser: It means "group on the constant 2" except MySQL where it means "group by column position2" it is deprecated too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: I think the count is of the columns, not the non-aggregate columns.  @gbn: the GROUP BY _n_ notation (and parallel ORDER BY _n_ notation) was standard in SQL-86 when aliases were not available, but was superseded in SQL-92 and beyond by aliases, though I don't think it was formally removed from the standard until quite recently.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: agreed, don't know when it was removed.

Comment: and what if i want sequence to be printed in result... like count for 0-30 then count for 61-90 like this ... even if i dont find any count for say 61-90 it should print 0 for that...

Comment: @PramodShivhare: you should probably add your comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use User Defined Function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CaseGrouping(@age int)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  return 
    case
    when @age < 0 then 'less than 0'
    when @age >= 0 and @age <=30 then '0-30'
    when @age >= 31 and @age <=60 then '31-60'
    when @age >= 61 and @age <=90 then '61-90'
    when @age >= 91 then '91+'
    when @age = null then 'NO INFORMATION'

else 'no catagory' END
END
```

And then your select will look like this:

```
select count(id), dbo.CaseGrouping(age)
from queue where DATE between '01-Apr-2011' and '05-May-2011'
group by dbo.CaseGrouping(age)
```

/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the main part of your query in a sub-query, effectively giving the CASE expression a name that can be used in the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT class, COUNT(id)
  FROM (SELECT id,
               CASE
               WHEN age < 0 then 'less than 0'
               WHEN age >= 0 and age <=30 then '0-30'
               WHEN age >= 31 and age <=60 then '31-60'
               WHEN age >= 61 and age <=90 then '61-90'
               WHEN age >= 91 then '91+'
               WHEN age = null then 'NO INFORMATION'
               ELSE 'no category'
               END AS class
          FROM queue AS q
         WHERE q.date BETWEEN '01-Apr-2011' AND '05-May-2011'
       ) AS g
 GROUP BY class;
```